# Do I need to query HasStateAuthority?

Tags: photon

Following a Photon Fusion tutorial, I wrote this code:

```
    public override void FixedUpdateNetwork() {
        if (!HasStateAuthority) {
           return;
        }
        ...
    }
```

I thought the condition on HasStateAuthority comes to prevent a player to change the state of other players. So I thought that, without this condition, a player movement action would move the objects of all players in the scene.

However, when I remove this condition, I do not notice any change in movement: the player input actions still move only that player's object, and not any other player.

Is it really needed to query `HasStateAuthority`?

Comment: There is as well `HasInputAuthority` which seems to be the correct one when you as well write about player input.